# Opposite of the ideal notch filter

Tags: filter, signal-processing

I know that the ideal notch filter passes all frequencies but one, but is there a filter that passes only one frequency and blocks all others? What is do you call such a filter and what is it used for (if anything)?

Comment: Parallel LC tuned circuits pass all but one.
Series LC tuned circuits block all but one.

Comment: It is possible to use a notch filter (I'm thinking of the twin-T notch filter: 3R, 3C) as a feedback element in an active circuit that does the function you're outlining...a single-frequency pass filter. There are other RC-type bandpass filters that are not quite as fussy about component tolerances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A high Q Bandpass filter  will do this .Tuned circuits were used a lot and are sometimes still used today.